# Trouble with communicating with an AD5292

Tags: spi, digital-potentiometer, atxmega

I have an AD5292 connected to an ATXMEGA's D port SPI and am supposed to communicate with it. Alas, it doesn't react to my commands.

(Instead of a "real" pullup resistor, I have activated the ATXmega's internal pullups, but at low speeds (about 500 kHz), at least *that* seems to work.)

According to [its data sheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5291_5292.pdf), I am supposed to have CPOL = 0, CPHA = 1 - which means SPI mode 1. Trying modes 0 and 2, I get the data which I put in back, but shifted by 1 bit. Modes 1 and 3 give me the same data that I put in.

As said, I get the same data back from the device that I sent to it, even if I issue read commands (read RDAC register, read memory, read status register), and the device ignores my requests to change the resistance. So it seems to ignore *all* commands.

I already hat the idea that I do something wrong with the SYNC/CS line, but if I omit that line, the device only gives me back 0 bits, so probably the SYNC line is activated correctly as well.

Besides the communication problems, I notice that the device constantly holds the RDY pin LOW.

These two problems are probably related to each other. I think that if I fix the RDY line problem, the other one is gone as well. (Resp.: if I fix their common root cause, both are g0one.) But I cannot figure why the device would hold RDY low all the time.

Did anyone of you experience the same problem?

Comment: Did you read the section on page 23 of the datasheet entitled **Write Protection** that begins *"On power-up, the shift register write commands for both the RDAC register and the 20-TP memory register are disabled"*?

Comment: @RogerRowland Yes, I saw this and tried to obey it. But my problem starts obe step earlier - even reading out the status register is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

I had a big problem with these initially and it turned out I wasn't sufficiently respecting the 2 millisecond delay after power on / reset, before sending it the first command. The chip ignores you if you send the setup commands (0x1803 etc.) too soon after power on.
See tPOWER-UP in table 7 of the data sheet.